# How to Pass Date from jquery to C# using Page Method

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, date

I am passing Date having `format('dd/mm/yyyy')` from jquery to `C#` using `Page Method`. When i pass  date `31/07/2014` to `PageMethod`, it gives me error `31/07/2014 is not a valid value for DateTime.` 
Here is my Code..

```
 var dto = { 
            'StudentList': StudentList, 
            'StudentFeeList': StudentFeeDetail, 
            'StartingDate': $('#txtStartingDate').val(), 
            'ClosingDate': $('#txtEndingDate').val() 
          };
```

this `DTO` is passed to `PageMethod`. I am saving data at this time.

While retrieving `Date` from `DataBase` i have converted it like this.

```
convertDate = function (jsonDate) {
   var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
   return date.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
},
```

Any Help.. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to retrieve and send this date calue.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when converting its taking it as mm/dd/yyyy as per your system date time, whenever you post/convert use Universal format i.e. YYYY-MM-DD

Using universal format is universally accepted format and will not give any issues when converting IT or TO to any format needed.

Comment: Ok try to post something like 07/07/2014 and see if it still gives issue.

Comment: No if day value is equal or less than month, then its ok.

Comment: Yes this is because of same reason I mentioned, try to send it in universal format and you will be good.

Comment: StartDate=`01/08/2013` and ClosingDate=`31/07/2014`, for StartDate its ok, but on closingDate its give me error.

Comment: This is because its converting it into MM/DD/YYY and taking MM as 31, as this is not valid thats why its giving error.

Comment: But its required to show `Date in dd/mm/yyyy` format, to Client,Then how i will handle it..??

Comment: You can always show it as needed on UI, we should only care it when we convert it into any form.